# Spring MongoDB $size query throws exception "org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException"

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-mongo

I have tried two types of query

1. Through repository

   ```
   @Query(value="{blockedAccounts : { $size : 1 }, updatedDate : { $gte : ?0 }}")
   public List<ChatRoom> findAllByAccountAndUpdatedDate(Date updatedDateGreaterThan);
   ```
2. Through normal spring query

   ```
   public List<ChatRoom> findAll(Account account) {
   Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("accounts").is(account).and("updatedDate").gte(CommonUtils.getPreviousDate(1)).
           andOperator(Criteria.where("blockedAccounts").exists(true)
           , Criteria.where("blockedAccounts").size(0)));
   return findAll(query, ChatRoom.class);
   ```

Both the times am getting Mapping Exception:

```
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException

    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/CyberDust] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for class java.lang.Integer] with root cause
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for class java.lang.Integer
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:684)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.toDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertAssociation(QueryMapper.java:248)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword(QueryMapper.java:145)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$Execution.readCollection(AbstractMongoQuery.java:123)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$CollectionExecution.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:146)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.findAllByAccountAndUpdatedDate(Unknown Source)
at com.mentionmobile.cyberdust.dbservices.ChatRoomDbService.findAll(ChatRoomDbService.java:64)
```

and

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/CyberDust] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for class java.lang.Integer] with root cause

    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for class java.lang.Integer
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:684)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.toDBRef(MappingMongoConverter.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertAssociation(QueryMapper.java:248)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedKeyword(QueryMapper.java:145)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)
at com.mentionmobile.cyberdust.dbservices.IDbServiceImpl.findAll(IDbServiceImpl.java:60)
at com.mentionmobile.cyberdust.dbservices.ChatRoomDbService.findAll(ChatRoomDbService.java:47)
```

I think the problem lies with my query method, but not sure where to look into.

Can someone point me to the right direction?